# Arduino Integer error

Tags: c++, arduino

We are trying to initialize a character array but it we get an error saying that we can not as we can not mix integers and chars, but we dont have have integers initialized.

thanks in advance

```
 void setup()
 {
     Serial.begin(9600); //Set the serial monitor.
     lcd.begin(16, 2); //Set the LCD
 }

 char line1 [5] = {0};
 char line2 [] = {0};

 void loop()
 {
     if (Serial.available() > 0) { //If the serial monitor is open it will read a value.
         line1 = Serial.read();
         delay(10);
         Serial.print(line1);
         lcd.print(line1);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Arrays are not assignable, so `line1 = Serial.read();` isn't allowed. Perhaps you meant to `strcpy(line1, Serial.read());`? But beware of buffer overflows. In particular, `line2` seems prone to them (it's a one-element array).

Comment: This does not look like C (in c an array is not an assignable lvalue. Is it C++?

Comment: Using ESP I'm going to guess `Serial.read()` returns a single `char` and that's the actual line it's telling you is the problem.

Comment: It is not C++ , and daniel how would I go about implementing this into my code?

Comment: Aurduinos use has a java looking syntax which creates c code in the when the user "compiles" it. Hence this is not c code but the aurduino runs on c. Common missunderstanding :-)

Comment: Thank you WozzeC for clarifying that:) very helpful

Answer (score 5):

I am *not* an arduino guy, but I did stay at a Holiday Inn last night with access to Google :)

http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read

`Serial.read()` returns a single byte (as an `int`). You're trying to assign that to a char array.

You can't do that. You can assign something to a specific element *in* an array: 
`line1[0] = 'c';` 
for example, but you can't assign to an array itself.

It *seems* like you're looking for `Serial.readBytes()`

http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadBytes

Which would look like:

`Serial.readBytes(line1, 5);`

in your case where `5` is the length of your buffer (array). This would read (at most) 5 bytes into your `line1` buffer.

**Edit to add:** That being said, it appears arduino's "C-Like" language is very much like C in that it expects "Strings" (`char` arrays) to be `null` terminated when passing them to `Serial.print()`. The advice above doesn't do that and in fact would cause problems.

What you would need to do is read up to *one byte less than the length of your array*, and then `null` terminate the "string" using the number of bytes actually read which is what `bytesRead()` returns to you (arrays are zero indexed):

```
int numBytesRead = 0;
...
numBytesRead = Serial.readBytes(line1, 4);
line1[numBytesRead] = '\0';  
Serial.print(line1);
```

Option B is to do as I originally mentioned, but loop and print one byte at a time from your `line1` array using the index:

```
int numBytesRead = 0;
numBytesRead = Serial.readBytes(line1, 5);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < numBytesRead; i++) {
    Serial.print(line1[i]);
}
```

According to the docs `Serial.print()` automagically knows to send a single byte/char when that's all that's passed to it.

Comment: +1, though I would add that arrays are not assignable because the OP doesn't seem to understand this.